# Is flagging for migration acceptable?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, flags

I've been around the original trilogy for a while now and have a pretty solid understanding on what belongs on what sites.  As of now, though, I only have vote-to-close priviliges on SF.

I'd like to help out SO and SU with migration when I see questions that are clearly meant for another site.  Is it acceptable to flag a question for mod attention so they can mod-hammer it over to the appropriate site?  Or is it better to just let the community sort it out.

One thing to keep in mind, and a big reason I'm asking this, is that there are times when a question will sit on the original site for quite a while before it eventually gets migrated.  If I see that happening I'd like to flag that, but I want to make sure that's not an abuse of the flag system.

Or maybe this is a community-specific thing that belongs on the individual site metas?

(sorry if this is a dupe, didn't see this particular issue addressed in other questions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is appropriate.

Often the community gets it wrong and there are only 4 other sites (apart from Meta) available to pick from. So a flag from someone will at least alert the moderators and they may have chance to divert the question to a better home.

Comment: Just to be clear, the "Off Topic" flag should be used for this, right?

Comment: @Gabe - It depends. If you think it should go to one of the 4 possible targets then "yes". If you think it should go somewhere else then "no". In the latter case just use a general flag and explain where you think it should go.

Comment: Thanks, I was even completely overlooking the Off Topic flag.....