# Add the "flag"-button to the close-vote review-queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags

When I review close-votes and come along an **Off-Topic**-question, I like to leave a flag for the mods to migrate the post to an other StackExchange site, if appropriate and if I know one (which is okay according to: [Is flagging for migration acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85485/is-flagging-for-migration-acceptable)).

The problem is, that in the review-queue, there is no "Flag"-button. So I have to close as off-topic, hit "back" in my browser to get back to the question, click it's link and flag it there.

Simply adding the "Flag"-button either in the top right corner (next to "Close", "Next", etc) or down below the question tags (like on the normally question pages) would speed this up.

Comment: why don't you vote for 'off-topic' and select the site to migrate to? Migration flags are only usefull for people who can't vote to close IMO

Comment: @WouterJ: that only works for the 5 sites in the short-list.

Comment: @WouterJ the list is not really "complete". Manual flagging is almost always needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use closing as a duplicate as a hack.

Secondly, the queues contain stripped down versions of the post, and are only meant to serve their primary purpose. Which is why you can't vote in the low quality queue (you're only supposed to comment and ask for deletion).  Similarly, the CV queue is for close voting, not flagging. If you want to flag the question, right-click on the question title>open in new tab, and flag there. (You may want to continue with a vote-to-close as off topic)

Comment: The first one was a typo, I meant to say "...close as off-topic". For the second part, it would just be faster to have this option right away. But I see multiple requests for more complete lists for the off-topic option around here, maybe this will help.